# Performance impact due to StackTrace constructor and getting method name

Tags: c#, performance, perfview

I have this piece of code in our logging library

```
var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
string operationName = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;
```

And as per my performance analysis using the PerfView Tool it shows up as

[image: Picture from PerfView etl file]

Does anyone know of the performance implications by the code that i have added?
If yes is there any other way that i can get method name without having greater performance impact?

I am currently running it as 1000 TPS on a 4 core machine. And i see that the it uses 15.1% of my CPU

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of C# 5, it would *definitely* be better to get the compiler to bake this into the call site instead, using [`[CallerMemberName]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx)

```
public void Log(string message, [CallerMemberName] caller = null)
{
}
```

Then:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    logger.Log("A message");
}
```

... is converted by the C# compiler into

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    logger.Log("A message", "DoSomething");
}
```

Comment: Great solution thanks. Will verify the performance with this code and will reply back.

Comment: Guess the reply back is still pending? :-D