# log4net conversion pattern not working with Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, log4net, .net-standard

I am using log4net-core-preview(2.0.6) in Asp.Net Web API Core 2.0, and my log4net config layout is

```
 <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d{hh:mm:ss} %logger [%M %line] %message%newline" />
 </layout>
```

and at Startup.ConfigureServices

```
//log4net stuff goes here ...
var logRepo = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
XmlConfigurator.Configure(logRepo, File.OpenRead("log4net.config"));
ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType());
log.Info("App is starting");
```

but I don't know why my logs look like this

> DEBUG 01:29:10 MyNameSpace.Controllers.XYZController [? ?] ,
>   somemessage

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here

thanks

Answer (score 7):

A little bit late but just run into this issue recently, turns out that some patterns are **not supported** under .NET Standard framework.

According to Apache's [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/framework-support.html), these features are not supported:

> - the ADO.NET appender
> - anything related to ASP.NET (**trace appender** and **several pattern converters**)
> - .NET Remoting
> - the colored console appender
> - the event log appender
> - The NetSendAppender
> - The SMTP appender
> - DOMConfigurator
> - stack trace patterns
> - access to appSettings (neither the log4net section itself nor using the AppSettingsPatternConverter)
> - Access to "special paths" using the EnvironmentFolderPathPatternConverter
> - Impersonation of Windows accounts

---

There are two workarounds:

1. Using C# 5.0's [Caller Info attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) with custom log wrapper, some good examples here:

   - [Improve Logging using C# 5.0 Caller Info Attributes](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/972/logging-csharp-caller-info-attributes)
   - [Learn How To Use log4net Logging in .NET](http://alokbhatt11.blogspot.com/2014/01/learn-how-to-use-log4net-looging-in-net.html)
2. Creating custom `PatternConverter` with `StackTrace` ([.NET Standard 2.0 and later
   required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45039126/900259)) shown as below

**StackTraceConverter.cs**

```
namespace MyWebApp
{
    public class StackTraceConverter : PatternConverter
    {
        protected override void Convert(TextWriter writer, object state)
        {
            try
            {
                StackTrace st = new StackTrace(true);
                int idx = 1;
                while (st.GetFrame(idx).GetMethod().DeclaringType.Assembly == typeof(LogManager).Assembly)
                    idx++;
                //I have to create a new StackTrace object in order to get the line number.
                var targetSt = new StackTrace(st.GetFrame(idx));
                writer.Write($"{targetSt.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().DeclaringType.FullName}.{targetSt.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name}({targetSt.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber()})");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**StackTracePatternLayout.cs**

```
namespace MyWebApp
{
    public class StackTracePatternLayout : PatternLayout
    {
        public StackTracePatternLayout()
        {
            AddConverter(new ConverterInfo
            {
                Name = "stack_trace", //your pattern name here
                Type = typeof(StackTraceConverter)
            }
        );
        }
    }
}
```

And **log4net.config**

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppenderCustomPattern" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    ...
    <layout type="MyWebApp.StackTracePatternLayout, MyWebApp">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5p %date{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} [tread-%t] %stack_trace - %m%n" />
    </layout>
    ...
</appender>
<root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppenderCustomPattern" />
</root>
```

Then log as usual

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ...
    public IActionResult LogForNetTest()
    {
        if (Logger.IsDebugEnabled)
            Logger.Debug($"Log4Net is ready to log!");
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The result is something like this

```
DEBUG 2018/07/02 15:30:59 [tread-9] MyWebApp.Controllers.HomeController.LogForNetTest(46) - Log4Net is ready to log!
```

---

Haven't fully tested yet but both methods work well so far,
though there are some differences between them:

- `Caller info attribute` can only get file path, `StackTrace` can get `AssemblyQualifiedName` or it's namespace with `DeclaringType.FullName`, providing more information.
- [Caller info attribute may have better performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33528483/900259%20%22%22)

Hope this will help.

Timmy.

Comment: Just a note to others when linking it up **layout type=** is "_FullClassPath, Assembly_"

Comment: It's not working for ASP.NET Core and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger :(

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/robsonj/Log4Net.Appenders

usage:<appender name="eventLogAppender"type="Log4Net.Appenders.NetCore.EventLogAppender, Log4Net.Appenders.NetCore">

Comment: - While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28227768)

Comment: Consider about @Adam s comment.

Comment: @Adam I'm not sure how the link to the review came about here. But since Late Answers are not done by multiple users, meaning it's not a process involves multiple reviewers that is done over time, it seems a little strange to leave a link to it.